# Where to store task from a task list

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, security, local-storage

I want to build a small Task-List Web-Application in Vanilla JS. 
Now I am wondering what is a good and safe way to store the tasks.

Local Storage would be the easiest and fastest but, I guess, not secure and backed up.

To store it in a MySQL DB would probably be the saftest way I guess?

How does, for instance, professional Task-Project Management web-apps like Asana probably store the tasks?

Many thanks for your help. :)

Comment: Hi Leon, Have you got any idea how to store data temporary except using local storage..

Comment: @ssatish4u thanks for your feedback. Yes, I do know that but I want to store them in a database, to have them secure and safe. After some research, I am now storing them in MongoDB Atlas, which works perfectly for me with JavaScript.